# Syntax error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I keep getting this error message when i try to run my debugger in VSC. Can anyone please help?
Here's a screenshot:

I'm pretty much new to programming and following a course, please keep explanations very basic where possible..

[image]

Here's the code for the JS file. I've generated a basic Visual studio code Extension using Yo Code and NPM.

```
    // The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
import { commands, window } from 'vscode';

// this method is called when your extension is activated
// your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate(context) {

// Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is 
    activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "content-helper" is now 
    active!');

    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with  registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    let disposable = commands.registerCommand('extension.helloWorld', function () {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed

        // Display a message box to the user
        window.showInformationMessage('Hello World!');
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
const _activate = activate;
export { _activate as activate };

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
function deactivate() {}

export default {
    activate,
    deactivate
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code causing this error. We will not be able to help you otherwise.

Comment: Sure, I basically used "yo code" and NPM to create an Extension.

Comment: Could you add more info for `lanch.json`

Answer (score 4):

VS code extensions are run in a Node environment which does not natively support modules (So no `import` and `export`).

`yo code` only uses `import` when you create a TypeScript extension. For js extensions, `yo code` instead uses `require`:

```js
const vscode = require('vscode');
```

To use `import` in a VS Code extension, you must compile the code down to target Node, either using TypeScript or a tool such as webpack

Comment: Thanks. What would I use instead of import and export?

Comment: `require` and `exports`: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules Or use a compiler like I mentioned

Comment: Hi Matt, could you elaborate a bit on "compile the code down to target Node"?

Comment: @laike9m Typescript needs to be compiled to Javascript (which will then be run by Node.JS) before it can run. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html

Comment: I am using TypeScript and I'm trying to load a JS dependency that uses `import` so I put `"module": "ES2020",` in my tsconfig.json and I get the error in the question.